# Facing issue in route codeigniter 3, how to pass params in route?

Tags: php, redirect, routes, codeigniter-3

I have defined a route `$route['category/(:any)'] = 'Store_controller/index/$1';` for `https://localhost/category/domestic` and its working fine. When someone redirected from my facebook page to this URL the URL changed to `https://localhost/category/domestic/?fbclid=JufJxsrRxxxP1SkxNxp`. A facebookid added as a new parameter in the URL and in this case it gives "products not found" error. I want to resolve the issue and keeping facebook id parameter in the URL.
Any feedback, suggestions will be highly appreciated.

I tried `$route['category/(:any)(.+)'] = 'Store_controller/index/$1';` for `https://localhost/category/domestic` but no success

Answer (score 0):

In your route modify it to receive 2 paramters

```
route['category/(:any)'] = 'Store_controller/index/$2';
```

In your Controller function add another parameter for `fbclid` with a default value

```
class Store_controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index($category, $fbclid = '')
    {
        ...
    }
}
```